# Algorithm on how to define XML based upon defined XML Format

Tags: java, algorithm

I have xml file that defines the expected data key ( also in xml) from the client. E.g.

```
<aa alias="a">
  <bb alias ="b">String</bb>
  <cc alias ="c">String</cc>
</aa>
<xx alias ="x">
  <bb alias ="b" >String</bb>
  <cc alias ="c">String</cc> 
</xx>
```

So in order to create the data file, the user can either used the actual tag or the alias tag as shown below

```
<a>
   <bb>Some Data</bb>
   <c>Some Data</c>
</a>
<xx>
   <b>Some Data </b>
   <c>Some Data </c>
</xx>
```

So, now to the question. When I am saving the data, I will need to store using the original key rather then the alias so what would be a good algorithm or data structure that I can use so as to get good performance. The crude way of solving this is that for each key I check the format xml and determine if it is the real Key or the alias. If alias is used then I will get the original key.

```
Thanks a lot
```

Comment: Why not resolving the aliases during parsing? Then inside your application you can work with a canonical format (the real tag names). Btw: I've no idea why one may need an XML format like the above?

Comment: Why don't you use an [XML schema (XSD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)) to define the structure of the XML? It's the standard and widely supported way.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use two data structures, a set (i.e. [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)) and a map (i.e. [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)).

The set would have all defined actual tags, while the map would have alias keys and actual tag values.

To determine whether a tag is an actual tag, you would use the `contains` method of the set (O(1) for `HashSet`). If it is not, get the real tag by using `get(alias)` on the map (O(1) for `HashMap`).

If there is a way of knowing beforehand whether a value is an alias or an actual tag, the set is not necessary.

Comment: I did thought of using HashMap, but the problem is that there would be large number of keys e.g. using the above sample for node b, the possible keys are xx:b => bb , xx:bb => b , x:bb => b, x:b . Hope I am clear as there is no way to create a lookup of key based upon user data as there is no way to know if they used alias or the real key unless I check each one of them.